# how remove binary image noise in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

after convert image to binary image (black and white ) if there is any noise how can
i remove that unwanted noise

you can see below  image have some white noise inside the black area how can i remove noise 
using opencv

http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/999/blacknoise.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it with [Erode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) and [Dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate).

Your image after `cvErode( in, eroded, NULL, 4)`:
[image: eroded]

And after `cvDilate( eroded, dilated, NULL, 4)`:
[image: dilated]

Comment: thanks already I found this article  befor but i can not understand what is going here

Comment: @user1190910 The article is not very good so I already edited my question. You should get pretty good results with just those two calls.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [floodFill](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill), passing a corner pixel as seed (or some other pixel that you know to be non-object).

You can see [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut4.html) an example of using erode, dilate and flood fill.